# Disabling some of UITextView actions on editable text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

iOS 10. Swift 3

I put this into my class with the UITextView. Seemed to be the best answer for removing some of the functionality in a popup menu. Initially had a issue with it crashing and I accepted and voted the answer to that question as correct... but on further testing.. I find the code simply doesn't work as intended.

Unfortunately **It infact does nothing**, absolutely nothing!! beyond compiling seemly catching the menu options and than doing them anyway, even if I trying to ignore them.

It seems it used to work in objective C as far as I can tell in other SO posts, but not in Swift? Has anybody managed to get a working version in Swift that looks like this perhaps, with some subtle code change I am missing here.

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (action == #selector(cut)) {
        return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Comment: You need to show the full error. You left out all of the important parts of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorganize your implementation a bit. It should be:

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (action == #selector(delete)) {
        return false
    } else {
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

As you had it, you were ignoring the result of `super.canPerformAction` and always returning true. That's bad because your class doesn't respond to every single selector.

Comment: No, I stand corrected. It doesn't crash and it also doesn't work :) seems to capture the action alright, but has no effect on the outcome. The action matching doesn't work at all it seems.